# raspberry pi 4 PlayOnLinux, metatrader 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4

I have a raspberry pi 4 with Raspbian and I have installed PlayOnLinux to run metatrader 4 but I don't get it to work. when I open PlayOnLinux and click on install nothing happens. what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So I ran into this problem as well. What fixed for me was click install "nothing" happened but then I noticed a new tab maximized new tab there it was .

Comment: Are you using metatrader as well? I bet the OP will benefit greatly from your answer if you add step by step instructions on how you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that PlayOnLinux is a Wine frontend, so unless you already managed to run Wine on ARM it will simply not work.

You can't get an ARM CPU run x86 code without emulation, and emulation is hard to get working and limited in performance. That Metatrader software doesn't look like it need a ton of performance, so maybe it will work via QEMU.